# SSH from PuTTy to Debian "authorized_keys is not a regular file" Error

Tags: ssh, debian, putty, ssh-keys

I cannot connect from my Windows 7 computer using PuTTy to a newly configured Debian Squeeze server using SSH RSA key authentication.

I get this error when running SSH in debug mode:
`User myuser authorized keys /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a regular file`

**What I've done so far:**

1. ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. Set passphrase.
3. Copied the id_rsa.pub file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. Copied the id_rsa to a text file on my Windows 7 machine
5. [Imported the key into `puttygen.exe` and converted it to a `.ppk` private key file.](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#S8.2.12)
6. Loaded that private key file into `pageant.exe` and made sure Connection->SSH->Auth Authetication methods had "Attempt authenticaiton using Pageant" checked.
7. Loaded the profile.

Based off of the [FAQ from OpenSSH.org](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14), I changed the permissions to the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Aug 13 14:16 /home
drwxr-xr-x 7 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 17 12:55 /home/myuser
drwx------ 3 myuser myuser 4096 Aug 17 13:24 /home/myuser/.ssh
drw------- 2 myuser myuser 4.0K Aug 17 13:23 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 myuser myuser  396 Aug 17 13:17 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub
```

I started debug mode on ssh, and got the following:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user myuser service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
User myuser authorized keys /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a regular file
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for myuser from 10.1.1.1 port 50710 ssh2
```

I'm at a loss as to what else to check. I haven't setup SELinux or anything. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is:

```
User myuser authorized keys /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a regular file
```

It appears you've made a directory named `authorized_keys` and put all your key files in it. This is why it's not working. `authorized_keys` is meant to be a regular file, and you can put all your keys in `~/.ssh`.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem is that `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should not be a directory. It is a text file that contains the public keys appended one line after the other.

Since you only have one key, simply move out the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub` file to a temporary location, delete the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` directory, then move back the public key file by renaming it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You should now be able to connect without using a login password.